# Reading excel data when the file is open

Tags: c#, .net, excel, connection-string, oledb

Few days back I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858310/reading-excel-fetchig-date-in-general-format#comment17403185_12858310) but could not find enough answers. I analyzed the problem a bit more and decided to create a new thread. If I should have not, let me know or close the question.

I have an **OPEN** excel file with a column in Date format with some values like 6/22/2006, 6/22/2006. I am trying to read the excel using OleDbDataReader. The code is like this:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", excelSheetName);
internal OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.CommandText = sql;
OleDbDataReader oleRdr = command.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
datatable.TableName = excelSheetName;
dataTable.Load(oleRdr);
```

I am using the connection string as:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\ExcelData\sample.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'";
```

The problem is I am not able to read the date values in correct (`DateTime`) format. I believe everything is treated as numeric format. So my result is

`6/22/2006 as 38890`

After reading some articles on internet, I understood my column is having multiple datatypes and then I changed my connection string as:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\ExcelData\sample.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0"";
```

But still I am not able to read the excel in correct format. Any suggestions on this. It looks a weird problem to me. Please let me know if I to need to provide some more information.

Note: Also make a note that when my excel file is closed both the connection strings give me the correct data. Also for new doc formats`.xlsx` we are using `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

**EDIT**

I tried editing the registry as well....but no relief.
But when I changed the value `IMEX = 0` or `IMEX = 1` it is working fine again. Can any one tell the exactly what is happening?

**EDIT 2**
When I changed `HDR=Yes` still everything worked good. Any help please? I could not find enough help on internet.

Comment: I'm confused with the EDITs. You can't read dates properly using Jet.OLEDB?.

Comment: Anyway you can always get a datetime from an Integer: 
DateTime.FromOADate(38890) ===> 6/22/2006 (You can try to parse as integer to know if you're reading a date or a OLE Date)

Comment: I am fetching those datetime values from excel to datatable and then passing as a datasource to a grid. these are for display purpose. Moreover....if user has a column with mixed column with some numeric values and some dates....your approach will convert everything to dates which is incorrect. I just want to read the data as it is present in the excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved the issue in a unsatisfactory way. I noticed with my analysis and experiments and ultimately concluded that when the excel is open in MS-Excel and we try reading the excel in C# using OleDbDataReader, some of the `DataTypes` are not read properly and unfortunately `DateTime` being one of them in my case.

As a solution, at present we are forcing the user to close the excel at the time we are reading the excel file. I even noticed that if the excel is open in `Read-only` mode in MS-Excel, then the data read is **correct** for all `DataTypes` including `DateTime`. But when opened in `Write-Mode`, then data read is **incorrect**.

These are my analysis results and I know/agree that the results are a bit weird. If any one disagree or have something else in their mind, then let me know and please correct me.

Comment: Super helpful but obscure post here. Other things that I used to defeat this issue: DateTime.TryParseExact, Integer.TryParse and DateTime.FromOADate.